# Mantener fijo ancho y alto de la vista

Tags: html, css, html5, frontend, design

Como se podria hacer que el tamaño de ancho y alto sea fijo, es decir no quiero tener medidas para cada dispositivo, asi tal cual se muestra quiero para todos, por ejemplo una tabla en mi vista escritorio, mantener eso en todos los dispositivos(celular,tablet, etc) que el usuario mismo maximice la pantalla

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.